# Reference item in group ( Textbox )

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I was using below line of code to edit word document's textbox. It is working pretty well.
`wdDoc.Shapes("T1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sh.Range("Q2"). Value`

- But now I made some changes in my Word document (template file).

1. I Grouped few items with **Shapes("T1")**.So now **Shapes("T1")** is inside **Group(3)**.
2. Now code give error, because it can't find **Shapes("T1")**.
   How can I reference **Shapes("T1")** within **Group (3)**?
   Thank you.

Only property I have found is **Shape.GroupItems**

Comment: According to the Microsoft documentation, Groupitems can be accessed with index, too. Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/word.shape.groupitems if this is what you are looking for (especially the sample code). I would expect that something like Shape.Groupitems("T1") should give you back what you need (but unfortunately I have currently no time to test it myself - therefore only as comment and not as answer)

Comment: Sadly it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
With wdDoc.Shapes("Group 3")
For x = 1 To .GroupItems.Count
If .GroupItems(x).Name = "T1" Then
With .GroupItems(x)
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sh.Range("Q2").Value
End With
End If
Next
End With
```

Comment: Or `wdDoc.Shapes("Group 3").GroupItems("T1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sh.Range("Q2").Value`

Comment: It is not working this way.